# Can you have a mix <div></textarea> in HTML5?

Tags: html, ckeditor

I am confused. In the [CKEditor documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-inline) I see:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="content"></textarea>
...
CKEDITOR.inline( 'content' );
```

Is it possible? What is the use of that?

Comment: If you're ever unsure whether a given piece of markup is valid, just [run it through a validator](http://html5.validator.nu/).

Comment: @MattBall It is actually invalid.

Comment: Dude, that's a typo mistake. It is perfectly **Invalid**.

Comment: Thx. Have just corrected this (https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/commit/237bcd7360cca0776f85fd15c6e0a483d4c404e1)

Answer (score 4):

That's a typo.

It should be

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="content"></div>
```

From Reinmar: When using `CKEDITOR.replace` then `textarea` is replaced. But when using `CKEDITOR.inline` then passed element may be a `div, p, h[1-6], etc` - every element specified in [CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dtd-property-S-editable). But not `textarea`.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. When using `CKEDITOR.replace` then `textarea` is replaced. But when using `CKEDITOR.inline` then passed element may be a `div`, `p`, `h[1-6]`, etc - every element specified in [`CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dtd-property-S-editable). But not `textarea`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an error in their documentation, as it would not pass validation. They meant `</div>` instead of textarea. The point is that you can turn anything that supports the `contenteditable` attribute into a CKEditor.